# ¿Como cambiar un dato tipo fecha a tipo de dato numérico en SAS?

Tags: sql-server, sas

Tengo un codigo que me trae la fecha actual

dt = date()

format dt YYMMN.;

Eso lo que me arroja en este formato es: 202002 
El date me da un numero de: 21963

Lo que necesito es poder tener el 202002 en numérico, no me sirve el 21963 porque necesito comparar ese 202002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto una forma de obtener lo que necesitas desde una consulta SQL.
Ya con eso lo puedes adaptar a tu base de datos para que lo reciba tu código.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SYSDATETIME(),112),1,6))
```